# Copy entire row from another sheet to sheet 1 if unique code typed in matches

Tags: excel, copy, excel-2007, excel-2010, excel-2003

https://www.dropbox.com/s/f83y17dedajbsz8/example.xls

That's a quick sample workbook of what I want this to work in.

Right now, sheet 1 (main) needs to have data from all the other worksheets copied to it manually. At the moment, what I am doing is I have a list of the unique codes I need, and I go to the sheet and ctrl+F for that code, then manually copy+paste that row into sheet 1 (main). It can be a bit time consuming.

What I want to do instead is to simply TYPE ANY unique code into any cell of column D on sheet 1, and then if that code matches the code on any of the other sheets, then the entire row will copy over to sheet 1.

Is this easily do-able?

Comment: Depending on how hard it is to find your unique code in the other sheets it should be fairly simple to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following VBA should do the trick, you need to copy it into the workbook code section for `Sheet1 (Main)`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim Index As Integer
Dim Count As Integer
Dim Match As Range

    If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Or Target.Columns.Count > 1 Then
        ' You've done something that has edited lots of cells. Cant handle this.
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set Sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")

    If Not Intersect(Sheet.Range("D:D"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        ' The edited cell falls in the range D:D
        Count = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

        For Index = 1 To Count
            If Not ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Index).Name = Sheet.Name Then
                Set Match = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Index).Range("D:D").Find(What:=Target.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not Match Is Nothing Then
                    'copy the line across
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Index).Range("A" & Match.Row & ":E" & Match.Row).Copy Sheet.Range("A" & Target.Row)
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next Index

    End If

    If Match Is Nothing Then
    ' optional, if the target string is  not found clear the line.
        Sheet.Range("A" & Target.Row & ":E" & Target.Row).ClearContents
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked absolutely perfectly, and thanks so much for commenting the code. That made it so much easier to adapt to other worksheets too. Thanks so much!!